# How to generate output as sound in python..?

Tags: python, audio

I am generating random number in python as below,

```
print random.randrange(100, 1000, 2)
```

Is there any way to convert that output to sound(audio) format..?

Comment: What should that number represent? Pitch? Duration? Start [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. I assume you are trying to generate a random number and convert it into an audio stream. If so there is a module called `PyTTSx` which you need to install separately with pip. Here is a quick example

```
import pyttsx
import random
data = pyttsx.init()
d = str(random.randrange(100, 1000, 2))
data.say(d)
data.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Thank you boss,Its working I need exactly this.Can i slow down the voice response..?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the speed:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.setProperty('rate', 70)

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
    print "Using voice:", repr(voice)
    engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
    engine.say("Hi there, how's you ?")
    engine.say("A B C D E F G H I J K L M")
    engine.say("N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z")
    engine.say("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9")
    engine.say("Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday")
    engine.say("Violet Indigo Blue Green Yellow Orange Red")
    engine.say("Apple Banana Cherry Date Guava")
engine.runAndWait()
```